# Compiler error message "error: could not convert from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}'|"

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, writefile, c-str

I'm trying to make a function that writes a file, but I'm having issues passing a string as a parameter.

```
void writeFile(string filename, string letters, int size)
{
     ofstream outputfile("output.txt");
     outputfile << letters;
     outputfile.close();
 }

int main()
{
    string letters[] = {"u", "l", "s", "n", "m", "z", "a", "p", "b"};

    int size = 9;

    string filename = "Inputfile.txt";

    writeFile(inputfilename.c_str(), letters, size);

}
```

And I get this error:

> error: could not convert from 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string*}' to 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}'|

Comment: What's `unsortedValues`?

Comment: Where is the variable `unsortedValues`? The error indicates that it's a `string*` instead of `string`.

Comment: Should that be `letters` instead of `unsortedValues`?

Comment: Why are you using `inputfilename.c_str()` when the `filename` argument is supposed to be a `std::string`, not a C string?

Comment: letter is an array of string, your writeFile() function takes a string in the second parameter.

Comment: UnsortedValues was meant to be a string that is supposed to be sorted. To simplify the code and issue i shortened it down a bit.

Comment: We won't magically know what unsortedValues is. What if your error is in the way you sort letters into unsortedValues?

Comment: @SaltyCode `writeFile()` just wants one string to write to the file, but you're giving it an array. The error message is very clear about that.

Comment: @KC Wong yeah sorry about that. But as you suggested i changed the parameter to expect an array as `string words[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of `string` items is passed as actual argument, where the formal argument is a single `string`.

You could replace the array with a single string.

Or with a set, or whatever suits the purpose, but then you'll have to change the called function accordingly.

---

The error mentions `std::string*` instead of an array, like `std::string[9]`, because the array expression *decays* to an expression denoting a pointer to the first item, which it does because the array is not being bound to a reference or passed to `sizeof` or anything where the expression's array nature would have to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
void writeFile(string filename, string letters, int size)
```

is expecting a string but,

```
string letters[] = {"u", "l", "s", "n","m", "z", "a", "p", "b"};
```

is an array of string. I "fixed" it by changing the function second parameter to

```
void writeFile(string outputFileName, string words[], int arraylength)
```

With "fixed" I meant that regardless of that, now it does create a file named "output.txt", but the content is not the array of string passed as a second parameter.